# Javascript to copy text from select field to text field

Tags: javascript, select, text

I am trying to copy the values from a select field to a text field

I came across this

http://jsfiddle.net/f23uP/

But when I created a test page using the following it does not work, I have obviously put it together wrong :(

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>

<title>Test copy select</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('select').change(function(){

  $('input[type=name]').val($('option:selected',this).text());
  $('input[type=price]').val($(this).val());
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <select>
      <option value="10">Apple</option>
      <option value="20">Orange</option>
    </select>

    <input type="name" />
    <input type="price" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your javascript in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function(){

    $('input[type=name]').val($('option:selected',this).text());
    $('input[type=price]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

See [this post](//stackoverflow.com/questions/30753333/why-document-ready-is-used-in-jquery) for further explanation.

Comment: Also add `http` or `https` to the `src` if/when running locally. Sometimes it can cause issues and fail to load the required library. I have experience this issue before hence this suggestion for you to add into your answer.

Comment: You can certainly add another answer, or add a comment to OP's post.

Comment: Thank you for the help and link